# How to implement once only controller in k6

Tags: k6

How to implement the once only controller in K6 like the one we have in Jmeter. I need to run the login page once for every thread and rest of the API's multiple times.

I have tried using scenarios in K6, but that is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In k6, you can achieve a functionality similar to JMeter's once-only controller by using the [init stage](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/test-lifecycle/#the-init-stage) of a test. The init stage runs once per [VU (virtual user)](https://k6.io/docs/misc/glossary/#virtual-user) before the [VU stage](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/test-lifecycle/#the-vu-stage).

You can find a similar example at https://community.k6.io/t/unique-login-for-each-virtual-user/5563/11.

You can implement this by keeping a variable in the init phase that informs you if the virtual user is already logged in. If it hasn't, do the login operation and keep the cookies, auth token, etc. for that VU.

I hope this helps!